# Janrain Engage Social Login Looks Messed Up in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, janrain

Has anyone else been able to make Janrain Engage and Bootstrap 3.x play nice?

Since updating my project to use Bootstrap 3, the Janrain Engage sign-in widget looks messed up and seems to overflow outside of its borders. According to [a post on the Janrain community forum](https://community.janrain.com/entries/25014521-Bootstrap-3), this is due to Bootstrap's use of `box-sizing: border-box;`. Janrain claims they cannot make any changes because they need to continue to support IE7, but that as of January 2014, they were discontinuing support for IE7. Nevertheless, the change has not been made and it still looks messed up.

Here's what the Janrain Engage sign-in widget looks like in Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

And in Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Unfortunately, the community forum is apparently no longer open for users with free accounts, and I can't seem to get a response from the Janrain engineering team.

I tried disabling `box-sizing: border-box;` on `<div id="janrainModalOverlay">`, but it negatively impacts the rest of the layout.

Has anyone else figured out a simple fix for this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a very simple fix for this. I'm not sure why I didn't come across this before. In your CSS file, add the following:

```
#janrainModal {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Hope that helps someone else out there who is struggling with the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the Janrain modal is not always sized correctly. Perhaps due to CSS conflict such as font size? I couldn't spend much time on finding out why, so used this quick/dirty solution:

The following js makes the appropriate css fix after the jainrain modal is initiated. A timer is used to wait 'till the modal starts. A better solution is to bind to a more appropriate event. I'll post an update (if no one else does) later.

```
$('.janrainEngage').click(function() {
window.setTimeout(function(){
    $('#janrainModal').css('width', '450px')
                    .css('height', '170px');
    $('.janrainContent').css('width','95%')
                        .css('height','90%');
},50);
});
```